# SCons - integrating custom builders for CUDA, CORBA etc

Tags: python, c++, cuda, scons, corba

For a a heterogeneous (C, C++14, Fortran95, python3) project, I'm currently evaluating what advantages over CMake SCons will provide to us for the integration of platform compilers and compiler wrappers for CUDA (7.5), CORBA (omniorb-4.2.1), MPI2 (MPICH) etc.

To get started, I created a project root directory ('data/projects/snippets' in the SConstruct script attached) with a subdirectory 'model', [in which the 'echo.idl' of the omniorb4 Documentation](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/omni42/omniORB/omniORB002.html#toc4)

```
interface Echo { 
    string echoString(in string mesg); 
};
```

resides (an `echo_i.cc` with an `int main()` will be generated by `omniidl` used with the -Wbexample switch), and a subdirectory-tree 'include/cuda_samples_inc', which is a copy of the the 'common/inc' branch of the CUDA Toolkit Samples, and copied the CUDA Toolkit Samples

```
2_Graphics/simpleGL/simpleGL.cu
```

into the project root directory.

My customized SConstruct

```
import os

CORBA_PASS = False
CUDA_PASS = True

CUDA_FAIL = not CUDA_PASS
CORBA_FAIL = not CORBA_PASS

EXE_SUFFIX = None
if os.name != 'posix':
    raise NotImplementedError('Only on POSIX platforms yet')


PROJECT_ROOT = '/data/projects/snippets'  # your mileage will likely vary

INCLUDE_DIR = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'include')
LIB_DIR = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'lib')

SYS_LIBS = ['dl', 'pthread']
GL_LIBS = ['glut', 'GLEW', 'GL', 'GLU', 'X11']
CORBA_LIBS = ['omniORB4', 'omnithread']


class CUDAEnvironment(Environment):
    CUDA_ROOT = '/usr/local/cuda-7.5'
    CUDA_BIN_DIR = os.path.join(CUDA_ROOT, 'bin')
    CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS = os.path.join(INCLUDE_DIR, 'cuda_samples_inc')
    GENC = "-gencode arch=compute_%d,code=sm_%d "
    GEN_RANGE = [20, 30, 35, 37, 50, 52]
    GENT = "-gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52"
    GENS = " ".join([GENC % (n, n) for n in GEN_RANGE]) + GENT

    COMPILE = """\
        %s/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I %s -m64 %s -o $TARGET -c $SOURCE \
    """ % (CUDA_BIN_DIR, CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS, GENS)

    LINK = """\
        %s/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I %s -m64 %s -o $TARGET $SOURCE \
        -L%s, %s\
    """ % (CUDA_BIN_DIR, CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS, GENS, LIB_DIR,
           ''.join([' -l%s' % (s,) for s in GL_LIBS]))

    def __init__(self):
        super(Environment, self).__init__()
        C = CUDAEnvironment  # class alias

        self.Append(PATH=":".join([os.environ['PATH'],
                                    C.CUDA_BIN_DIR]))

        cu2o = Builder(action=C.COMPILE, suffix='.o', src_suffix='.cu')
        o2exe = Builder(action=C.LINK, suffix=EXE_SUFFIX, src_suffix='.o')

        self.Append(BUILDERS={'CU2O': cu2o, 'O2EXE': o2exe})


if (CUDA_PASS):
    CUDA = CUDAEnvironment()
    CUDA.CU2O(['simpleGL.cu'])
    CUDA.O2EXE(['simpleGL.o'])

if (CUDA_FAIL):
    CUDA = CUDAEnvironment()
    o = CUDA.Object(['simpleGL.cu']) # line 63
    CUDA.Program(o)


class CORBAEnvironment(Environment):
    IDL2CC = """
        omniidl -bcxx -Wbexample $SOURCE
        cp `basename $SOURCE .idl`SK.cc `basename $SOURCE .idl`.cc
     """        
    COMPILE = """\
        g++ -std=c++14 -I. -Wall -pedantic %s $SOURCES -o $TARGET
    """ % (''.join([' -l%s' % (s,) for s in CORBA_LIBS + SYS_LIBS]))

    def __init__(self):
        super(Environment, self).__init__()
        C = CORBAEnvironment  # class alias

        idl2cc = Builder(
            action=C.IDL2CC, suffix='.cc', src_suffix='.idl'
        )

        cc2exe = Builder(
            action=C.COMPILE, suffix=EXE_SUFFIX, src_suffix='.cc'
        )

        self.Append(BUILDERS={'IDL2CC': idl2cc, 'CC2EXE': cc2exe})


if (CORBA_PASS):
    CORBA = CORBAEnvironment()
    CORBA.IDL2CC('echo.cc', os.path.join('model', 'echo.idl'))
    CORBA.CC2EXE('echo', ['echo.cc', 'echo_i.cc'])

if (CORBA_FAIL):
    CORBA = CORBAEnvironment()
    skel = CORBA.Object(os.path.join('model', 'echo.idl'))  # line 98
    impl = CORBA.Object('echo_i.cc')
    CORBA.Program([skel, impl])
```

works well with the switches `CUDA_PASS` and `CORBA_PASS` enabled, but for the

```
CUDA = CUDAEnvironment()
o = CUDA.Object(['simpleGL.cu']) # line 63
CUDA.Program(o)
```

resp

```
CORBA = CORBAEnvironment()
skel = CORBA.Object(os.path.join('model', 'echo.idl'))  # line 98
impl = CORBA.Object('echo_i.cc')
CORBA.Program([skel, impl])
```

blocks, scons gives up due to that sort of error I was afraid of:

```
scons: *** While building `['simpleGL.o']' from `['simpleGL.cu']'
Don't know how to build from a source file with suffix `.cu'.  
Expected a suffix in this list: ['.c', '.m', '.cpp', '.cc', '.cxx', 
'.c++', '.C++', '.mm', '.C', '.f', '.for', '.ftn', '.fpp', '.FPP',
'.F', '.FOR', '.FTN', '.f77', '.F77', '.f90', '.F90', '.f95', '.F95',
'.f03', '.F03', '.s', '.asm', '.ASM', '.spp', '.SPP', '.sx', '.S'].
File "/data/projects/snippets/SConstruct", line 63, in <module>
```

resp.:

```
scons: *** While building `['model/echo.o']' from `['model/echo.idl']':
Don't know how to build from a source file with suffix `.idl'
[same as above]
File "/data/projects/snippets/SConstruct", line 98, in <module>.
```

Sadly,

> how to build from a source file with suffix `<suffix>`

is just what I tried to tell scons with my custom environments and builders.

So my question is:

**How to integrate custom environments and builders so that the SCons `Object()` and `Program()` builder facade can be used?**

The [Scons Builder() doc](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-builders-writing), esp. [18.2. Attaching a Builder to a Construction Environment](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idp1378917444) seemingly just explains the syntax used in my `PASS` blocks along with passed-though `Program()` invocation, but not how make e.g. 'Object()' aware of the custom builders.

It goes without saying that python itself could be used to hand-code virtually every kind of behavior or add-on, but I want to stay within the realm of the SCons toolset as much as possible.

versions:

`SCons 2.3.1` (but that is not craved in stone, if an update to 2.4.1 will help, I'll do that) run with `python 2.7.9`

Comment: What does this question have to do with CUDA programming? Why is it tagged with the CUDA tag? Isn't a purely an `scons` configuration questiton?

Answer (score 2):

SCons has the notion of a `src_builder`. It's a keyword (usually added to the constructor of the Builder class) that informs the system how to create the actual C/CPP source files by running an additional builder first.
Check out the Tool `engine/SCons/Tool/qt.py` in ll. 315 where it says:

```
# register the builders 
env['BUILDERS']['Uic'] = uicBld
env['BUILDERS']['Moc'] = mocBld
static_obj, shared_obj = SCons.Tool.createObjBuilders(env)
static_obj.add_src_builder('Uic')
shared_obj.add_src_builder('Uic')
```

. By calling `add_src_builder` the Uic builder gets registered with the static and shared Object builders each. Then, if an `*.uic` file is given to `Object` directly, SCons checks its list of defined source builders, converts the `*.uic` to its corresponding `*.cc` file and then passes the latter on to the Object builder.

Comment: **Thanks a lot**! That's definitely a big step ahead, at least  the `Object()` call for the CORBA works (after some trivial mods of my code) with a .idl. Issue is, that the CU2O tool already produces an `.o`, and scons rightfully complains about  `Multiple ways to build the same target [...]  simpleGL.o` if I try to add my `CU2O` as as a `src_builder`. In addition I'm now the hunt for some use of the related  `Tool.createProgBuilder(env)`  to also plug my exe builders under the  `Program()` call. I'll update my code when I have a substantial progress and would like to drop you a line if I may.

Comment: Once you've successfully mastered the creation of an Object file, you should let the default handler for Program handle the linking step. Don't provide a specialised builder for linking each of your objects into the final executable. Instead, initialise a separate environment for each build task where you require different paths and/or settings. You'll also want to use the special variables like CPPPATH for include directories instead of hardcoding the "-I" flags into your command call, because the former let's you build on Windows as well.

Comment: Since you're starting with SCons, and looking at your current build specification, I'd also suggest that you subscribe to our user mailing list (scons-users@scons.org , see also http://scons.org/lists.php ) and start to ask your further questions there. You'll reach a much broader audience of SCons experts there...and response times are usually very short.

Comment: I'll certainly subscribe to that list; ty for that tip.

Comment: Ok, using your recipe I got the CORBA env part working acceptably smooth. But for the CUDA build, using the `add_src_builder` method to make scons recognize the '.cu' suffix,  leads to the already mentioned  `Multiple ways to build the same target were specified for: simpleGL.o  (from ['simpleGL.cu'] and from ['simpleGL.o'])` error. Although I understand the reason for this error, I don't know how to avoid it while maintaining the comfort of declaring `.cu`  as a source suffix (aside from decomposing nvcc's generation of object files from .cu into multiple steps)

Comment: There are several duplicates for this error message here at SO. It's probably better to open a new question, after checking that none of the other already existing answers aren't helping you out.